# What causes accented Hindi / Thai characters to incorrectly word-wrap in a resized TextField and how to resolve it?

Tags: flash, localization, textfield, word-wrap, diacritics

First of, I don't understand this language - so my apologies if this is not Hindi or Thai!

Now, if you take a close look at the two textfield examples below, I highlighted the characters to focus on.

In the first picture (top), the last character on line 1 is **accented**.

See for yourself (photo zoomed-in for illustration purposes):

[image]

However the character in the second picture (bottom), shows that after shrinking the TextField by a pixel or two will "shift" the accent character to the next line combined with an **'o'** looking character.

**The Question is:**
What causes this accent to shift on the next line? And how can it be displayed correctly?

**System Information:**

- Flex SDK 3.6;
- Flash Builder;
- Flash Player 11.0.1.152;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Hindi. The "o looking character" is the placeholder used when a Hindi diacritic is displayed without a letter to put it on. They could just display the diacritic over empty space like ´, but for some reason they prefer a circle to represent the character that should be there.

The problem is related to how diacritics are written for Hindi. To make it easier to understand, I will use a European accented letter for my example, the letter é. There are two possibilities:
1. é can be one character. If you hit backspace, the entire character disappears.
2. é can be two characters, e and ´, where the ´ contains placement information so that the result looks like é rather than e´. If you hit backspace, only the diacritic disappears and you have to hit backspace again to remove the e.
For European languages, you don't generally see 2). For Thai, both 1) and 2) are in use (which creates a problem for search because one-character é doesn't match two-character é). For Hindi, there are too many diacritics and possible combinations, so only 2) exists.

So, since you have two characters rather than one, the only solution is to write own line-break code. This would also give you the opportunity to prevent line-breaks occurring in the middle of the wor
d, which is never nice.

Comment: Thanks, that confirms I was going in the right direction! I started to write my own line-break code before I got any feedback on this. +1 :)